# Best Practice for gitlab ci. Multiple small docker images or one big?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

Is it better to use multiple tool-specific docker images in `gitlab-ci` rather than one general purpose, larger docker image?

E.g. create one docker image containing `jdk`, `kubectl` and `terraform`, or use a `jdk`-image for the `jdk`-jobs, a `kubectl`-image for the `kubectl`-jobs and one `terraform` image for the `terraform`-jobs?

How is this commonly approached, taking into account that there's no "official" `terraform`-image and no "official" `kubectl`-image, so I would need to build and maintain them myself.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, this really is a matter of opinion. Personally, I think the best approach is to use one container per process, because that's what a container is meant for, isolate a process. Also, the smaller the image the better in terms of size, build speed and possible reuse of layer.

However, other people think it's better to build an image with many tools for the sake of simplicity.

Which one is correct? Both. At the end of the day, it really depends on your criteria.

Also, the lack of official images is not an indicator of whether a process is suitable to be run in docker or not.